# basic refresher needed: regexp syntax to replace a grep that doesn't work

Tags: regex

This will probably take any of you folks about 1 minute to answer, so I apologize for the brain lapse.  But I've overthought this so much that I am totally forgetting what I know is simple regexp using Perl.

I have an array @array containing several values:

```
    ball_123456789
    glove_234578901
    bat_1458158568
    ball_6319254815
    hat_2343581451
    ball_again_3353585885
    ball_4845555555
    racket_343581558
```

... and I want to extract *only* the elements in the array beginning with "ball_" (but not "ball_again_", above.)  In other words, I want @found to include ball_123456789, ball_6319254815, ball_4845555555.

Obviously something like "@found = grep /ball_/, @array" isn't effective because it would grab not only "ball_123456789" but "ball_again_3353585885".

What I lack is enough knowledge in regexp to formulate an effective pattern-matching statement.

Help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ball_\d+
```

This simple regex should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/29

Comment: YES.  Thank you vks.   This was one of those deals where I had looked at the overall code for so long that I'd literally lost sight of the simple solution I needed.  Thanks for the reminder!